# Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression?

Tags: sql, ms-access

hello and thanks in advance for any help.

I am getting an error: 'Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression' and I do not know why... any ideas?

This is my query:

```
 UPDATE 
table1

SET 
table1.country_name = table2.COUNTRY,
table1.city = table2.CITY ,
table1.state = table2.STATE 

FROM
 ( table1 
inner join
table2 
ON
 table2.SITE_ID = table1.SiteID )

where
table1.country_name is null;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no FROM clause in an [UPDATE query in Access/Jet SQL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/update-statement-HP001032282.aspx):

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.SiteID = table2.SITE_ID
SET table1.country_name = table2.COUNTRY,
    table1.city = table2.CITY ,
    table1.state = table2.STATE 
WHERE table1.country_name is null;
```

Comment: Using UPDATE....FROM is perfectly acceptable look at the definition here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: @John: That link is to Transact-SQL (ie, MS SQL Server).  This question is tagged with ms-access.  Different (more limited) syntax.  See link in my answer.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Access 2007... if that could have anything to do with the error...

Comment: @tyler: The fact that you are using Access is indeed what is causing the error.  The version of Access is not relevant in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Lose the parenthesis around the joined tables.  In addition I would personally make an alias for table1 and table2 and reference the table1 alias in the update. Like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET 
  t1.country_name = t2.COUNTRY,
  t1.city = t2.CITY,
  t1.state = t2.STATE 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.SITE_ID = t1.SiteID
WHERE
  t1.country_name is null;
```

Comment: @tylercomp Then your omitting telling us something as I just ran a test scenario on my SQL Server.

Comment: Check the tags.  The missing information you're asking about is `ms-access`.